# What is clang's equivalent to --no-undefined gcc flag?

Tags: macos, gcc, clang

I am trying to build a project on Mac OS X using clang and it fails on linking step with `ld: unknown option: --no-undefined`, which is meant to built with gcc.
What's the clang equivalent for this option? (Please, don't advise to use gcc instead of clang.)

Also, a more generic question, is there any resource where one can find some kind of a "mapping" between gcc and clang (linker) options differences?

Thank you.

Comment: That's a linker option. Use `-Wl,...` and read the doc of your linker (`ld`). With gcc, you can add `-v` to see what option it actually passes to the linker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OS X uses a different [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker#OS_X_and_iOS). As @rubenvb points out, it's probably the one from [Apple's binutils](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/). If you run `man ld`, and search for "undefined", you will find this option:

> -undefined treatment
>                    Specifies how undefined symbols are to be treated. Options are: error, warning, suppress, or dynamic_lookup.  The default is error.

So, replace `-Wl,--no-undefined` with `-Wl,-undefined,error`. Also, use the Force, Luke.

Comment: Are you sure OS X uses LLVM's `lld` and not [Apple's binutils](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/)?

Comment: @rubenvb You are more likely to be right than my "educated" guess :) `ld -v` says that it uses LLVM3.5 for LTO. I read more into it than I should have. Removing that part from the answer. If you don't mind, please edit it with the right information.

Comment: Your answer is fine the way it is currently, but for completeness a link to [the status section on the lld website](http://lld.llvm.org/#current-status).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Pradhan. My bad, didn't think of looking into ld man. It worked with one correction: had to use `-Wl,-undefined,error` - otherwise it fails with `clang: error: no such file or directory: 'error'`.